# Cast Device GoogleApiClient.onConnectionFailedListener always being called

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am having trouble debugging why my connection to a cast device is always failing but works fine in other apps that are not mine.

I am getting a reference to the cast device but i am never able to connect to that device in my own implementation using:

```
        private void connectToCastDevice(CastDevice currentDevice) {

        // Create the CastOptions.Builder
        Cast.CastOptions apiOptionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions.builder(currentDevice, mCastClientListener).build();

        // If the GoogleApiClient is not null and is Connected
        if((mGoogleApiClient != null))
        {

            // Disconnect from the Client
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

            // Set the Client to null
            mGoogleApiClient = null;
        }

        // Instantiate the GoogleApiClient Object
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                                        .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder)
                                        .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
                                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mConnectionFailedListener).build();

        // Connect to the ApiClient
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

Here is what my Log is sorry for the late update:

07-29 22:28:49.608: I/MediaRouter(2888): Unselecting the current route because it is no 
longerselectable:MediaRouter.RouteInfo{uniqueId=com.google.android.gms/.cast.media.CastMediaRouteProviderService:16f658a34d13c744277d3755727a7762, name=old reliable, description=Chromecast, enabled=true, connecting=false,  playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, volumeHandling=0, volume=0, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1, extras=Bundle[{com.google.android.gms.cast.EXTRA_CAST_DEVICE="old reliable" (16f658a34d13c744277d3755727a7762)}], providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }

What does this mean?

Comment: How do you know you are not connecting? Are you testing on a real hone? What does the log file show?

Comment: I've restarted my device now, and im getting !status.isSuccess() when launching application. Yes this is a real device setup in the console and all. Should i be using setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true)? status.describeContents() is resulting in 0

Comment: Which status are you referring to? I don't see that in your code, and yes, turn on the verbose logging and see the log.

Comment: So when i onConnected is called the Bundle is always null, the verbose logging does not seem to be telling me much i will try to post some more information

Comment: Bundle argument for onConnected() would be null in almost all cases (except in transient connectivity recovery case), so if onConnected is called, you are connected.

Comment: hmm so then it seems i am failing to launch the application. I will provide some logs

Comment: its working again but I needed to kill all google play services and restart my device. What would be causing this some sort of memory leak in my cast application life cycle?

Comment: You had to reboot to get the cast icon visible, or to get connectivity going or to launch app? As was said multiple times, you need to look at logs

Comment: No to get connection. I realize my input is not the best at this time. I am trying to get more detailed logs. I will update when i can.

Comment: @AliNaddaf When you get a chance view the log above. Thanks

Comment: That log means the device disappeared so connection to it also is dropped. It may be caused by an issue (https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=314) which will be fixed in the next play services update which is coming soon.